# Fetching Facebook Ad spends grouped by campaign names

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api, facebook-ads

I wanted to fetch the daily ad spends in Facebook based on campaigns separately, ie, for each campaign with its spend.
I have tried with API call, but that gives state wise classification. How do I group based on campaign names?

```
"https://graph.facebook.com/v14.0/act_xxxxxx/insights?" + encodeURI("level=ad&fields=spend&access_token=FB_ACCESS_TOKEN&breakdowns=region,country&time_range={'since':'2022-08-09','until':'2022-08-09'}&filtering=[{\"field\":\"country\",\"operator\":\"CONTAIN\",\"value\":\"US\"}]&limit=100")
```

Answer (score 0):

Campaigns and adsets has an insights field where you can read performance and spending metrics.

**Get insights from campaigns endpoint**

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v14.0/act_xxx/campaigns?fields=name,insights{spend}
```

you can use date filters with you calls to get lifetime spending.

you can also get spending from campaign adset insights field.

**Check the official documentation**
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-campaign/insights